# How to check user shared something or not in the by esys-flutter-share plugin

Tags: android, flutter

How to check user shared something or not in the flutter by esys-flutter-share plugin

```
try {
    await Share.text(
      'Accessale Sharing',
      " It is an awesome classified ads app, Download Now",
      'text/plain',
    );
    
  } catch (e) {
    print('error: $e');
    Toast.show('Share failed try again', context, duration: 4);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `Share.text(...)` returns `void` and you cannot get any data from it. By that said you cannot predict what was the action of the user by using `esys-flutter-share`. [Here](https://github.com/esysberlin/esys-flutter-share/blob/master/lib/esys_flutter_share.dart) you could see what is happening 'underneath'.